# Login to Openshift from Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, openshift, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently logging into Openshift by updating my token in the jenkins file. However since the token is dynamic this is not a plausible design.

I am running commands like  `sh "oc start-build foo --from-dir=docker/foo --follow"`

In Blue ocean I get an error saying I need to be logged in once it hits the `oc` commands

Answer (score 0):

Use the openshift plugin for Openshift:

```
openshift.withCluster() { }
```

[Documentation on Openshift plugin for Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/openshift-client-plugin#configuring-an-openshift-cluster)

OR

Configure jenkins to use a private key and you not have any issues. If you are using a username and password than `openshift.withCluster() { }` will be needed.